# Prove the following language is not regular using the Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

I am trying to use the Pumping Lemma to prove the language $$L=\{a^nb^mc^md^n\}$$ is not regular. However, I am having trouble when selecting the values of x, y, and z to show that xyz is contained within the language (before proceeding to show that it is not contained in the language when selecting a value of i for v, as uvw = y, where |v| > 0.)

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What values can $n$ and $m$ take?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for sake of contradiction that $L$ is regular, and let $p$ be the pumping length.

Consider the word $a^p bc d^p$. If we write this word in the form $xyz$ such that $|xy| \le p$ and $|y| > 0$, then $y=a^k$ for some $0 < k \le p$. But then $xy^2z = a^{p+k} bc d^p \notin L$.